# String.Format Format a array

Tags: c#, string.format

Is it possible to format a array of values when you don't know in advance the number of elements in the array.
I have tried this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", x));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This produces "1".

I am trying to output 1,2,3 or "1","2","3"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `string.Join`:

```
var result = string.Join(",", x); // 1,2,3
```

or:

```
var result = string.Join(",", x.Select(n => "\"" + n + "\"")); // "1","2","3"
```

Reffer [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)